# RxSwift: Extra argument 'onError' when subscribing on an Observable<String>

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have the following code:

```
let fetcher = DiagnosticFetcher(commandSender: sender)
fetcher.fetch()
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe(
       onNext: { self.store.save(content: $0) },
       onError: { self.view.showError("Error") },
       onCompleted: { log.verbose("Diagnostic fetched") })
```

It does not compile: `Extra argument 'onError' in call`. I get the same error if I use `onSuccess` or `onDoesNotExistButShowTheBug` instead of `onNext`.

The `fetch()` method returns a `Observable<String>` (whose last operator is a `reduce`). It seems that the `subscribe()` call expects only one lambda:

```
fetcher.fetch()
   .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
   .subscribe(onNext: { self.store.save(content: $0) })
```

Results in: `Extraneous argument label 'onNext:' in call`. And:

```
fetcher.fetch()
   .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
   .subscribe({ self.store.save(content: $0) })
```

compiles fine.

I feel like I get the wrong `subscribe()` implementation. I want that one:

```
public func subscribe(onNext: ((ElementType) -> Void)? = nil,
                      onError: ((Swift.Error) -> Void)? = nil,
                      onCompleted: (() -> Void)? = nil) -> Disposable {
```

but obviously, the compiler doesn't.
I'm using XCode 9.2 with Swift 4 and RxSwift 4.1.1.

I have other parts in my app that use the `onNext:onError:` on an observable where it works. I can't put my finger on what is different for this call.

Any thought on how I can identify the root of the issue?

Comment: Did you try adding the full implementation (with onCompleted)?

Comment: Yep, I've updated the question to add the `onCompleted`

Comment: open issue on github

Comment: I see that the one in the source (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxSwift/ObservableType%2BExtensions.swift) has an additional argument - onDispose. Could you try a call to this?

Comment: Probably just a copy/paste issue but `onError: { self.view.showError("Error"),` is missing a `}` closing bracket

Comment: I've tried the  `onDispose` but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: You're right @Scriptable, thanks for the catch! Copy/paste issue indeed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it to compile by specifying the first parameter in the `onError` lambda:

```
fetcher.fetch()
   .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
   .subscribe(
      onNext: { self.store.save(content: $0) },
      onError: { _ in self.view.showError("Error")})
```

Comment: I can't believe no one has upvoted this answer yet!, Thanks for sharing your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding my contribution.

I had the same issue but, in my case:

```
recordHeader.albumArray.asObservable()
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] value in
        self?.populateView(recordHeader: value)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The value type of the function "populateView" didn't match to value type of value